# Compiling Opencv from SVN

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I had succes compiling both release and debug mode of opencv, using cmake and visual studio 2010.

I used the precompiled stuff earlier, but needed some modifications to the build.

I told cmake to build it into my opencv source dir/build/x64/vc10 and ended up with both debug and release folder there, possible to tell it just to put it all in the same folder?

The build/include folder only have CMakeFile folder and 3 project files. Where are the include files to include in my projects. When downloading the precompiled one, they are all in the build/include folder. Something wronge with my build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the generated solution and build the `INSTALL` project for both Debug and Release  configurations and you will have all needed binaries and headers in the `build/install` folder.

[image]

Comment: Theres only All_BUILD and opencv_ffmpeg package_source perf and uninstall in the solution.